# Using GridSearchCV with xgbranker

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, ranking, valueerror, grid-search

I am trying to use GridSearchCV with xgbranker estimator from xgboost. I am trying to use GroupKFold and passing qid (group_ids) parameter to the grid fit method but it's not straightforward. After a bit of hit and trial with solutions already suggested on the web, I finally zeroed on a approach. I am still getting an error which seems to be in the scoring method passed. Any help or working example would be great?

Sample code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupKFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, ndcg_score

ndcg_scorer = make_scorer(ndcg_score)

param_grid = {
'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.02],
    'n_estimators': [10, 50]
}

splits = 3
gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=splits)
cv_group = gkf.split(X_train, y_train, qids_train)

def group_gen():
    for ids,_ in cv_group:
        yield ids

grid = GridSearchCV(my_model, param_grid, cv=splits, scoring=ndcg_scorer, refit=False)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train, qid=next(group_gen()))
```

I get below error:

*ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got multiclass instead*

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be related to the scoring method you use, but you didn't share anything about your data. so it's hard to say what exactly is the problem.
It seems to me that you're using for the scoring a method that expects something else then you're providing as a label.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).